# Does it possible that transaction.atomic does not work as expected?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

[image]

This is a DRF API View for entry like. When someone like a entry, i will insert a like record into table `entry_like`, and plus by 1 to field `likes_num` in another table `entry`. But, something went wrong that some of the count of `entry_like` records corresponding to one entry is less than the field `likes_num` in table `entry`. I do not know why it does not work as expected even the `post` method is with decorator `transaction.atomic` on. Are there some cases that the decorator `transaction.atomic` does not run as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I think it is the case that `transaction.atomic()` does not work the way you expect.

To understand what it does, you have to understand SQL's transaction isolation levels and exactly what behavior they guarantee. You don't mention what database you're using, but PostgreSQL has good [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html) on the subject.

Your expectation seems to be that it will work as if the isolation level was `SERIALIZABLE`. In fact, the default isolation level in Django is [`READ COMMITTED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-READ-COMMITTED). And in that isolation level, if you have two of these transactions operating at once, they will both overwrite `likes_num` with the same number.

One solution is to use an F-object instead of setting `likes_num` to a specific value. In that case, the new value will be based on whatever value is in the field at the time of the write, rather than what value was in the field at the earlier point when you read the row.

```
entry.likes_num = F('likes_num') + 1
```

The other solution is to use `select_for_update()`, which will lock the `entry` row. It's better to avoid locks if you can, so I would opt for the F-object version.

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation. I really appreciate it.

Comment: BTW, how to test the situation of high concurrency?  I can not reappear the situation using python multi-threading.

Comment: @Gorgine: I don't think you need to test high concurrency per se, just the race condition. So maybe you could run two instances at the same time and mock one of the function calls to insert a `sleep()`, to ensure that both `get()` calls happen before either one commits. (You can probably find other answers about testing race conditions in Django, I'm just thinking out loud.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use F objects

```
from django.db.models import F

...
entry.likes_num = F('likes_num') + 1
entry.save()
```

Because you do not have any errors in code execution and two transactions are valid.

Comment: I guess that many requests are recved in the same time caused the problem.

Comment: Does F object will lock the status in case other requests modify the field value?

Comment: no, it just will be translated to likes_num = likes_num + 1 in sql

Comment: Got it. Maybe  i can use `select_for_update` to lock until transaction finished.

Comment: I think this is another way, and also is possible)

Comment: Yep, but it is not easy to test. Anyway, thx for ur solution.